# UIActivityIndicatorView won't show in UIWebView

Tags: ios, webview, loading, uiactivityindicatorview

I have a UIWebView that i would like to show an activity indicator in while the page is loading. I have added the UIWebViewDelegate and added the indicator in the .xib file but it still doesnt show.

```
-(void) webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    [webView addSubview:loadingView];
    [webView bringSubviewToFront:loadingView];
    [loadingView startAnimating];
}

-(void) webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    [loadingView stopAnimating];
}
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that your `IBOutlet` for `loadingView` is connected to the view object in the interface builder.